# How to replace [[ in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace `[[` with `[` using javascript but my code does not work. Please help me. Thank you
I tried this code before:

```
this.pairs = this.pairs.replace(/[[/g, '[')

this.pairs = this.pairs.replace('[[', '[')
```

Comment: Try escaping the brackets `.replace(/\[\[/g, '[')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

square brackets `[` have a special meaning in RegExp, and that is for [Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You need to escape the brackets in order for it to be considered a literal string:

```js
let result = '[[ This contains [ some brackets[['.replace(/\[\[/g, '[')

console.log(result)
```